# Mapping Multiple Classes to a Table in Hibernate, Without a DTYPE Column

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two hibernate classes: a base class, and an extended class that has additional fields. (These fields are mapped by other tables.)

For example, I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Book")
public class A {
    private String ID;
    private String Name;
    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Book")
public class B extends A {
    public String node_ID;
    // ...
}

public class Node {
    public String ID; // maps to B.node_ID
    // ...
}
```

How do I map this in Hibernate? [The hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168) states three types of inheritence configurations: one table per class, one table with a type column, and a join table -- none of which apply here.

The reason I need to do this is because class A is from generic framework that's reused over multiple projects, and class B (and Node) are extensions specific to one project -- they won't be used again. In the future, I may have perhaps a class C with a house_ID or some other field.

**Edit:** If I try the above pseudo-code configuration (two entities mapped to the same table) I get an error that the DTYPE column doesn't exist. The HQL has a "where DTYPE="A" appended.

Comment: If these classes are mapped to the same table without discriminator column, how would Hibernate distinguish which is which?

Comment: @axtavt that's the point; every instance of B is also an A.

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is possible by mapping the `@DiscriminatorColumn` and `@DiscriminatorValue` to the same values for both classes; this can be from any column you use that has the same data regardless of which type (not sure if it works with null values).

The classes should look like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Book")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="published")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="true")
public class A {
    private String ID;
    private String Name;
    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Book")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="true")
public class B extends A {
    public String node_ID;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm getting `org.hibernate.MappingException: Entities [B] and [A] are mapped with the same discriminator value 'true'`. (Hibernate version is 5.3.7 if this matters).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who got here like me and does not want to have the dtype column but instead want to use the same table for more than one entity as is I would recommend using [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/map-multiple-jpa-entities-one-table-hibernate/)

Basically you can create a Base like this

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseBook<T extends BaseBook> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    ... any other variables, getters + setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name= "book")
public class BookA extends BaseBook<BookA>{ 
  //Default class no need to specify any variables or getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name= "book")
public class BookB extends BaseBook<BookB>{ 
  @Column(name = "other_field")
  private String otherFieldInTableButNotMapedInBase

  ... Any other fields, getter/setter
}
```

From the above we have created base super class which does not have any entity or table mapping. We then create BookA to be default with the Entity + Table mapping. From there we can create other Entities all extending from BaseBook but pointing to one table