# Extending a table in Hibernate which has some relations

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an Entity that would like to extend it by adding some fields. first of all they are not accessible to me to change directly, they are in their own jar file. here are the base entities:

```
@Entity
table(name="ACCOUNTDEF")
public class EtAccountDef

{
private String cNumber;
private List<EtAccount> accounts = new ArrayList();

public String getCNumber()
{
  return cNumber;
}

public void setCNumber(String cNumber) {
  this.cNumber = cNumber;
}

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="accountDef")
public List<EtAccount> getAccounts() {
  return accounts;
}

public void setAccounts(List<EtAccount> accounts) {
  this.accounts = accounts;
}
}
```

which is the parent class and the below is child class:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="ACCOUNT")
 public class EtAccount
 {
   private Double accountAmount;
   private EtAccountDef accountDef;
   private List<EtAccountItems> accountItems = new ArrayList();

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   public EtAccountDef getAccountDef() {
     return accountDef;
   }

   public void setAccountDef(EtAccountDef accountDef) {
     this.accountDef = accountDef;
   }

   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="account")
   public List<EtAccountItems> getAccountItems() {
     return accountItems;
   }

   public void setAccountItems(List<EtAccountItems> accountItems) {
     this.accountItems = accountItems;
   }
 }
```

so I tried these changes to achieve my goal.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class OtAbstractAccount extends EtAccount {
    private Double AccountCommission;

    @Column(columnDefinition="decimal(15,2)")
    public Double getAccountCommission() {
        return accountCommission;
    }
    public void setAccountCommission(Double accountCommission) {
        this.accountCommission = accountCommission;
    }
```

and then extend it by this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACCOUNT")
public class OtCostumAccount extends OtAbstractAccount {
}
```

The fields are now added to the base table(EtAccount) but
after compiling I get an error in the Weblogic that says:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne
>   on EtAccount.accountDef references an unknown entity: EtAccountDef

I have entered these two line in my ORM file:

```
 <mapped-superclass class="package.OtAbstractAccount" /> 
 <entity class="package.OtCostumAccount" />
```

Surprisingly when i comment

```
 <mapped-superclass class="package.OtAbstractAccount" />
```

from ORM the weblogic does not rise any error but when I try to load object another error will be created that say:

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00904:
>   "OtCostumAccount "."DTYPE": invalid identifier

I'm confused whit these error and I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you will find your answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868124/mapping-multiple-classes-to-a-table-in-hibernate-without-a-dtype-column

Comment: @sgraton thanks for your comment but it does not worked for me. as well I can not change any property of EtAccount entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not modify the parent class, then the default hibernate inheritance strategy apply: one table per class. This strategy require a discriminant column which, by default, is DTYPE. Did you try to add a discriminator column to your OtCostumAccount entity or create the DTYPE column ?

Comment: I have added these lines but same error
 @DiscriminatorColumn(name="OtIAcc", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING, length=10)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="iAccount")
public class OtCostumAccount extends OtAbstractAccount {